# how to hardcode bytes in solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix, hardhat

How can I hard code `bytes` in solidity for a static call?

Ive tried:

`bytes memory data = "0xfeaf968c";`

`bytes memory data = \xfeaf968c";`

It works when I manually enter it as an input parameter, while it fails for some reason when I externally call it when its hard coded in this format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the hex keyword to hard-code bytes in your contract.

`bytes memory data = hex"feaf968c";`

or

`bytes memory data = "\xfe\xaf\x96\x8c";`

Comment: using hex worked, although the second suggestion errored: `ParserError: Expected ']' but got ','`

Comment: `"\xfe\xaf\x96\x8c"` also seemed to work

Comment: updated second example, had to look how i did it in one project :D

Comment: now the second one is returning `0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000fe00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000af0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000096000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008c`

Comment: cause its dynamically-sized byte array, maybe stick to the first one

Comment: I edited the answer and added a solution. I feel we have a strong answer. Thank you so much for your help!